# program print out numbers with an interval (5500) that are divisible by 2 and 3 (c++)

Tags: c++

I am stuck on how to do this I am also required to use for loop
I'm not asking you guys to write this whole programming but please tell me where to start from
this is one idea I had but it doesn't really work

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    cout<<"enter a number";
    cin>>n;
    for (i=0; i<=n; i+=5500)
    {
         if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            cout << i << "number is devidible by 3 and 5 ";

       else
        cout<<i;
    }

}
```

Comment: `for (i=0; i<=n; i++)` since you want to increment one by one. Also change your if statements then it should be OK. `n` is the upper bound here also, so you can directly write *5500*.

Comment: You just change i+=5500 with i++. And also you should change the if statements with i%5  with i%2.

Comment: If a number is divisible by 3 and 5, it's divisible by 15 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop condition seems to be wrong:

```
for (i=0; i<=n; i+=5500)
```

This loop starts at `0`, stops at `n`, and increments `i` by `5500` after each iteration.

To iterate all numbers starting at `0` till `n` :

```
for (i=0; i <=n ; ++i)
```

Its not clear where the `5500` comes into play. Either you loop until `n` or until `5500`, not both.